# Strikeout and bold causes bold to leak out

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, answers

I posted an answer that had some bold text struck out and the bold attribute leaked out and affected the "link|edit|delete|flag" links and other stuff below the answer. I'll try it here and see what happens:

<s>**Bold Struck Text**</s>

Comment: Yes, it made the tags and flair bold, too.

Comment: Try adding a blank line at the end.

Comment: Pretty good catch.

Comment: I added some white space at the end of the question above. It still leaks.

Comment: I actually like the bold **`status-review`** :)

Comment: @voyager's mask: As I understand it, one of the rules of typography is that you should use a heavier weight when you have light text on a dark background (or some sticklers say avoid reverse-contrast altogether - but I think that refers to runs of text).

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: I believe that that is the rule of thumb for full paragraphs, but a single bold tag draws more attention to it. If the rest of the tags were to be kept with a normal weight, the *`status-review`* tag would be more visible, specially with the different color.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: Just for the record: **I don't endorse full paragraphs written with a bold font-face because that is ugly and rude. If you (you being anyone thinking in doing it) do it, I'll come personally and hit you with a big `<b>` tag.**

Comment: @voyager's mask: I would hit them with a <blink> tag, but that's just me.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: `<blink>` would be a hit or miss... May be a `<markee>`? No, that wouldn't work... Mmm...

Answer (score 2):

Good catch! This was a bug in the tag balancer. The updated code is here:

http://refactormycode.com/codes/360-balance-html-tags

Answer (score 1):

Your markup:

```
<s> **Bold Struck Text** </s>
```

Gets mangled to this:

```
<strong>Bold Struck Text </s>
```

You could switch out your shorthand of `<s>` into the proper `<strike>` tag:

```
<strike> **Bold Struck Text** </strike>
```

Comment: I could, but the site shouldn't allow formatting to leak out of user content into site content.

Comment: isn't `<del>` the proper, semantic tag for strikethrough, and `<strike>` the deprecated one? (like `<b>` vs `<strong>` and `<i>` vs `<em>`)

Comment: @Kip You're right with `<del>` but `<b>` and `<i>` are still in vogue. Like when you mention the title of a movie, you're not necessarily emphasising it as would be if you used `<em>`.

Answer (score 0):

Further testing:

<s>**bold and struck with s and double asterisks to start things off**</s>

<s>struck with s</s> and not

**bold with asterisks** and not

**bold with b** and not

*italics with one asterisk* and not

*italics with i* and not

<strike>struck with strike</strike> and not

**strong** and not

Now some unterminated tags:

struck with s

**bold with asterisks

bold with b

*italics with one asterisk

italics with i

struck with strike

strong

Comment: Only the bold leaks out.

Comment: Sounds like the title of a maudlin country song.