# There appears to be another formatting leak

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Long answers are truncated in SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/long-answers-are-truncated-in-so)

The text "link|edit|flag", "answered Jan 16 '09 at 20:42", "Kyle Cronin" and "community wiki" on his answer **[here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12224/what-would-you-want-to-see-in-a-stackoverflow-api/12237#12237)** is in a fixed-width typeface apparently due to a formatting leak similar to the one I [reported earlier](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28021/strikeout-and-bold-causes-bold-to-leak-out) (which was fixed).

The answer in question consists of text, bulleted lists, a horizontal rule and some example code-formatted XML. It is probably the latter which is causing this behavior.

For some reason, the `<table class="fw">` is wrapped in `<code>` tags.

Comment: It's not wrapped in `<code>`, it's `<pre><code>` which aren't closed properly before their enclosing `</div>`, just before that table, apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a truncation issue -- I think this was a bug in the sanitizer that has since been fixed. That's why open/meaningless-edit/save fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

Added some whitespace to the end of [that particular answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12224/what-would-you-want-to-see-in-a-stackoverflow-api/12237#12237).
Fixed it because the answer was being truncated.

[It's a bit of an issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/truncated) with the unusually lengthy posts.