# Minor formatting bug

Tags: bug, status-completed

There seems to be a slight bug with the formatting on this answer: [Best way to reverse a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228038/best-way-to-reverse-a-string-in-c-2-0)

The issue I'm seeing is that the footer (`link|edit|flag` etc. at the bottom of the answer) is appearing in Consolas instead of the usual font. No other answer to the same question has this problem. I am seeing the issue in both IE8 and Chrome.

Here's a concatenation of images of two footers from the same question:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/55e21b59d6.jpg](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/55e21b59d6.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the post is all there, just leaking out, it's a [problem with the sanitiser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35742/there-appears-to-be-another-formatting-leak).

> [image: them blocks, they burst]

Meaningless whitespace edit fixes up the problem and pushes the content of the post back into its boundary.

Comment: could also be erroneous truncation, since the post was last saved (rendered to HTML) wayyy back in October of 2008. Either way.

Comment: It's always one or the other @Jeff

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you were able to notice that speaks volumes of your eyesight (and mine, I suppose).