# The case of the bleeding monospace font!

Tags: bug, status-completed, google-chrome, opera

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46347/grants-python-rep-tracker-updated-to-use-json-api) has a weird case of the mono, while [the preview doesn't](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/46347/edit).

Also, that question is missing some content at the end:

> [image]

Comment: We got a bleeder!

Comment: doesn't bleed for me (Firefox 3.6).

Comment: Why am I not seeing it?  Is it browser-specific?  (FF 3.0.18)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36418/minor-formatting-bug http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35742/there-appears-to-be-another-formatting-leak http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26721/long-answers-are-truncated-in-so http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13218/long-questions-on-stack-overflow-are-truncated-closed

Comment: **CODE BLUE! CODE BLUE!**

Comment: @json: Have you been kissing your monitor?

Comment: Try editing one of a posts in **Opera.** Hilarious results.

Comment: So this is `[status-completed]`? Kind of?

Comment: You'll have to give up a tag if you want status-completed.

Comment: @random: lose the browser specific tags.

Comment: @json @random - I'm pretty sure people will search more by the browser tags than the tag `bleeding-style`

Comment: @Pol, you either leave the `[bleeding-style]` tag or I'll add a `[mononucleosis]` tag.

Comment: @Popular, check the screenshots. The question was truncated and there was a `<code>` tag unclosed, giving a monospace font to things that normally shouldn't have one. Now it was fixed by editing the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The HTML was incomplete and needed to be refreshed from the markdown.  I did a trivial edit and this issue should be fixed for this post.

The SO team has elected not to go through the entire site fixing these problem posts so they have to be done by hand when found.