# How ( why ) did I get this font?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The case of the bleeding monospace font!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46351/the-case-of-the-bleeding-monospace-font)

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621117/how-do-i-fix-this-java-generics-wildcard-error)

[how http://a.imageshack.us/img153/7006/capturadepantalla201007b.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img153/7006/capturadepantalla201007b.png)

I don't know why is it like that, but I like it :)

This is the only question that looks like that.

Here's [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211035/fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-windows-h-and-scons) for comparison

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img190/1162/capturadepantalla201007h.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img190/1162/capturadepantalla201007h.png)

What could it be

Comment: Looks like a tag didn't get closed properly and the fixed width font is leaking out of the code block above... although I can't reproduce it on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is going on with that answer, except for the fact that a tag isn't being closed correctly by the SO engine. For some reason, your post is being cut off prematurely, i.e. parts of your question are actually missing from the source (and the rendered output).

I would suggest that you copy the entire [revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/2d1a0874-a26c-4625-9977-d2c9bc1f946b/view-source) and try pasting it into your question. Hopefully, that'll fix it. If it doesn't, then I would attribute the problem to the engine, since the markdown code you're using looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I noticed that too.  It happens, under certain conditions, when the font from the Markdown Editor bleeds into the page below it.  I've seen it before.  I'm using IE8.  Switching to IE compatibility mode makes the problem worse.

You will note that the problem goes away if you remove the `:S :S` from the line that reads, "I want to understand it!" ([see the new edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621117/how-do-i-fix-this-java-generics-wildcard-error)).

And yes, I also like that font in the tags.

Comment: it's just old markdown server-side parsed HTML being saved to disk many moons ago. A simple re-save will fix it, as we've updated to MarkdownSharp since then.

Comment: awm.. It looked nice :(