# Markdown formatting bug, code-tag not closed

Tags: bug, markdown, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The case of the bleeding monospace font!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46351/the-case-of-the-bleeding-monospace-font)

See this answer: [Most elegant way to generate prime numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042902/most-elegant-way-to-generate-prime-numbers/1072205#1072205)

Somehow the links below (like flag, edit etc.) are also in `<code>` style. This is a bug in the markdown formatting I guess

Comment: I saw after posting that this is a duplicate

Comment: Not reproducable on Firefox 3.5.4. Looks OK from here.

Comment: @Andreas_D Not reproducable is because I resaved that answer (see duplicates)

Comment: Ah, didn't know that.