# Answer Layout Bug in IE9/Chrome - Footer Encapsulated In Code Block

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, user-interface

Here's the link: [Dynamic enum in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725043/dynamic-enum-in-c)

If you scroll down to the answer that starts like this...

> Just showing the answer of Pandincus with "of the shelf" code and some
>   explanation: You need two solutions for this example ( I know it could
>   be done via one also ; ), let the advanced students present it ... So
>   here is the DDL SQL for the table :

You'll see that the user/timestamp information for that question is encapsulated in a code block.

**Edit**: Added image in case someone edits the post.

[image]

Comment: Not just IE9 / Chrome, getting it on FF7 too.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that this was an old bug (which I'm having trouble locating) in the server-side rendering process that has since been fixed. However, since the rendered view of posts is pre-generated, the broken view persisted beyond the point when that was resolved. The solution is just to edit the post to cause it to be rerendered, which I've done now.

Comment: I haven't found the old bug either (that edit is about as old as Meta itself, IOW: *really* old). Anyway, this is correct.

Comment: Because it TOTALLY MATTERS three years later: here's the original bug: [The case of the bleeding monospace font!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46351/the-case-of-the-bleeding-monospace-font)