# Part of a question doesn't appear. Missing a "Read More" Link?

Tags: bug, status-completed, information-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answer Layout Bug in IE9/Chrome - Footer Encapsulated In Code Block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104725/answer-layout-bug-in-ie9-chrome-footer-encapsulated-in-code-block)

I stumbled into this question which displays a very interesting glitch:

[Arithmetic underflow or overflow exception during debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56655/arithmetic-underflow-or-overflow-exception-during-debugging)

It seems that the text of the post stops after the *Jinxed!* section. And the `link|edit|flag` links, as well as the tags, the last edition date and the poster information are all displayed in bold. However, when one look in the [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56655/revisions), one notice that there is a ton of information which are not displayed on the main page.

Am I missing a "Read More" button, or have I found a display bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an extremely old and long fixed bug; once in a while these still show up, because posts are rendered once, and then stored that way (note that the last edit was from 2008). The solution is to make a dummy edit to force re-rendering. I just did that, and now it looks fine.

Comment: That is quite an arcane bug, next time I'll encounter it, I'll know what to do.