# Question getting cut off

Tags: bug, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answer Layout Bug in IE9/Chrome - Footer Encapsulated In Code Block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104725/answer-layout-bug-in-ie9-chrome-footer-encapsulated-in-code-block)

A portion of this question is truncated.

[Implementing Custom Profile Provider in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834166/implementing-custom-profile-provider-in-asp-net-mvc)

It appears correctly in the edit view so it appears to be an issue with the main question display.

Comment: Make an edit and save it. There's probably an old rendering bug that will be fixed when the HTML is regenerated.

Comment: Marc beat me to it. I did do a save, but I hadn't changed anything so I guess it didn't actually update the HTML.