# Stack Overflow code rendering bug

Tags: bug, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Answer Layout Bug in IE9/Chrome - Footer Encapsulated In Code Block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104725/answer-layout-bug-in-ie9-chrome-footer-encapsulated-in-code-block)

I was asked to post here because of a engine bug rendering a code snippet. My [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/435075/30568) appears cut off even though the code in the post is complete, and in my browsers (Firefox on both Windows and Mac OS X) the line immediately under the post (action links, time stamp of last edit and my flair) are rendered in a wrong (non-proportional) font.

[image]

When I edit the post the preview shows up correctly, it's only the answer on the page that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I went ahead and made the necessary dummy edit to fix your answer.