# Markdown rendering issue

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, markdown-rendering

[Windows is shutting down screen takes a long 20 minutes](https://superuser.com/questions/77887/long-shutdown-time) (revision 2) on SU renders the markdown incorrectly:

[image: screenshot]

This might be a duplicate of [The case of the bleeding monospace font!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46351/the-case-of-the-bleeding-monospace-font), but as I don't want to clutter SU's review queues I did not try out the answer.

Comment: Repro on FF 27.0.1, Windows XP.

Comment: Repro on IE 9, Chrome 33.0.1750.146 (Windows 7).